# Diff and merging of VBA in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vba, git, visual-studio, merge

We have a project with components written in Excel/VBA. We use Git on Azure Devops for source control.

The other components are written in C++ and we use Visual Studio 2017 as IDE. We use the VS Team explorer for the git operations. The VBA code is exported and imported from Excel using [vbaDeveloper](https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper) tool. The diff and merge tool is the internal vsDiffMerge.exe.

After a colleague recently rebased his development branch on master, the VBA code got corrupted on seemingly random places.

Some of the corruption seems to indicate that something tried to parse the text according to a syntax, for example:

- "Option Explicit" was changed to "Option Explicit On" on alot of places ([VBA](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) doesn't have that syntax, but [VB6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) does)
- Added parenthesis after calls to subroutines ([VBA](http://www.devguru.com/content/features/kb/kb100222.html) doesn't allow these for subroutines, only for functions)

Other kinds of corruption was just random:

- Missing declarations of parameters and variables, and functions
- Missing parts of code
- Random characters in code (e.g. chinese letters)

Is it possible that vsDiffMerge.exe has tried to be too smart here and interpret the VBA source code files (.cls, .bas, .frm) as VB6/VB.NET and done some own modifications?

Comment: Yes, it apparently is possible based on your description of the outcome (assuming vbaDeveloper isn't the culprit).  I'm not sure I understand the question though. Are you looking for another diff-merge tool? Configuration options for vsDiffMerge? Something else?

Comment: `Option Explicit` absolutely exists in both VBA and VB6. Your VB6 link is VB.NET.

Comment: I would be rather surprised if anything that works inside of Visual Studio .NET and is designed for working with .NET languages would properly work with VBA. VB.NET has a common ancestry with class VB languages, but they are *not* the same. I imagine vsDiffMerge works on the assumption this is VB.NET code and I very much doubt it will work correectly with VBA.

Comment: @Comintern I'm trying to determine the culprit here. What is really changing the code. I thought diff and merge tools only see the code as text Is Visual Studios vsDiffMerge.exe "smart" and configured according to a language? Do we need to use another diff and merge tool which treats the VBA code as plain text?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Only VB6 and VB.NET has the { ON | OFF } though. VBA doesn't support that.

Comment: No, VB6 doesn't have that.

Comment: [VBA also *does* allow subroutines, as does VB6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156851.aspx).